# How to delete a kwargs argument if it is empty?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, keyword-argument

I am working with arguments, variables that I go through GET
and I receive in my view to do my queryset, the problem is, if I receive an empty argument does not work, I explain more with code.

My url example:

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/my_view/?val1=xd&val2=lol&sox=`

My view.py

```
val1 = request.GET.get('val1', None)
val2 = request.GET.get('val2', None)
foo = request.GET.get('lol', None)

filters = {
    'code_field': val1,
    'tiempo_field__lte': val2,
    'code_id__exact': foo,
}

my_query = Babies.object.filter(**filters)
```

In this example sox is empty, that's why it doesn't work for me I think, what would be the elegant way if an argument comes empty is not taken in the query.

Comment: `if foo is not None: filters['code_id__exact'] = foo`

Comment: The problem is not that the URL has an empty value for "sox", but that it doesn't have "lol" at all. Your code doesn't care about the "sox" value, but `foo = request.GET.get('lol', None)` will set `foo = None` because there is no `'lol'` to `.get()`.

Answer (score 1):

#### filter the filter

Use a dictionary comprehension to filter the filter to remove any key:value pairs that have None for the value:

```
filters = {key:value for key,value in 
              {
                  'code_field': val1,
                  'tiempo_field__lte': val2,
                  'code_id__exact': foo,
              }.items()
              if value is not None }
```

The inner dict could be a list of lists or tuples, but then you have to type lots of '[]'s or '()'s.